# Does Parliament ratify Statutory Instruments made through the negative resolution procedure?

Tags: united-kingdom

Some UK laws are passed through the negative resolution procedure, whereby the draft is laid and then this automatically becomes law unless there is an objection from the House.

Does this meet the definition of ratification, or is ratification an active, affirmative action, and the negative resolution procedure, passive?

Comment: Hi Ben! I have a question for you [over on Chat...](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85183/discussion-with-ben)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Statutory instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statutory_instrument_(UK)) subject to the negative resolution procedure (formally, "[subject to annulment in pursuance of resolution of either House of Parliament](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo6/9-10/36/section/5)") are not ratified by Parliament at all.

Instead, the power to issue them, granted by Acts of Parliament, means that they can come into force immediately or on some later date - but that Parliament may annul them within 40 days if it wishes.

Hence there is no ratification, only a veto.